# How can i duplicate image in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I've UIImageVeiw. It's height must change dynamically by scrollview content size height. When I resize, it is changing the image quality. How can i duplicate image until it matches scrollview height? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont get that: " How can i duplicate image until it matches scrollview height?". Can you please explain in more detail what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to repeat my image in ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you must use a pattern image:

```
UIColor *patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"<your pattern image name>"];
<your view>.backgroundColor = patternColor;
```

Comment: it is not useful for me. This not background. It it UIImageView.

Comment: Well...change your UIImageView to UIView, and use the image that you have put in your UIImageView as pattern image ?

Comment: trust me, this is what you want. forget about your imageview, and set the backgroundcolor. anything else is just a hack.